# Why does one code require me to create an object, while the other doesn't?

Tags: java, oop

I have two pieces of code, one required me to create a new object and then call the methods using that object. Yet another code worked without me needing to create the object.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Wheel
{
    double radius;

    public Wheel (double radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    double getCircumference()
    {
       return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    double getArea()
    {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num = numInput.nextDouble();

        Wheel r = new Wheel(num);
        System.out.println(r.getCircumference());
        System.out.println(r.getArea());
    }
}
```

Here is the other.

```
public class GiveChange
{

    public static int getQuarters(int p)
    {
        return p / 25;
    }

    public static int getDimes(int p, int q)
    {
        return p / 10;
    }

    public static int getNickels(int p, int q, int d)
    {
       return p / 5;
    }

    public static int getPennies(int p, int q, int d, int n)
    {
        return p / 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int pennies = 197;
        int q = getQuarters(pennies);
        pennies -= q * 25;
        int d = getDimes(pennies, q);
        pennies -= d * 10;
        int n = getNickels(pennies, q, d);
        pennies -= n * 5;
        int p = getPennies(pennies, q, d, n);
        String str = String.format("The customer should recieve %d " +
                "quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, " +
                "and %d pennies.", q, d, n, p);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Is it because the second code has public static int, while the second one just has the data type.

Answer (score 0):

The `Wheel` class defines and instantiates an object to use inside of `main`.  The `GiveChange` class does not require an object for instantiation since you are working with `static` methods.

The difference between the two is simple - a `Wheel` holds state - like the radius of the wheel - but `GiveChange` does not hold any state in order to do its calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Also in the second code if you want to have a GiveChange object you should make new of that. but you are using static methods and you don't need to new object there.
For more information about java static methods visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)